# How does the expected risk change as we scale a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I wanted to understand what in the expected risk $R(f) = \mathbb E_{x,y \sim p(x,y) } [ \mathbb 1\{ f_W(x) \neq y \} ]$ when we scaled a classifier. To my understanding if we scale a classifier not matter how its parametrized, it will remain the same classifier, thus its expected risk should to change. This is easy to see in the discrete case with binary classification $\{ \pm 1\}$:

$$ R(f) = \mathbb E_{x,y \sim p(x,y) } [ \mathbb 1\{ f_W(x) \neq y \} ] = \sum_{x,y \in X \times Y} p(x,y) \mathbb 1\{ f_W(x) \neq y \} $$

because if $f_W(x) > 0 $ or $f_W(x) < 0 $ of the scalar is positive $ k >0$ then the sign would remain the same of course $k f_W(x) > 0 $ or $k f_W(x) < 0 $.

Unless integrals are unexpectedly different from summation is subtle ways I am not aware of, I'd assume that it should follow even when we are talking about measures and binary classification:

$$ R(f) = \mathbb E_{x,y \sim p(x,y) } [ \mathbb 1\{ f_W(x) \neq y \} ] = \int_{x,y}\mathbb 1\{ f_W(x) \neq y \} d \mu(x,y) $$

so my hypothesis is the expected risk:

$$ R(f) = R(kf)$$

if $k > 0$. **In particular this is true and doesn't only hold for a specific fixed test if we have one.** Is that true?

Also, does this extend to multi-class classification?

Last but not least, usually in classical learning theory bounds depend on the norm of the linear model. If this is the case, how is it that we can get bounds if we can always make the norm of the model smaller in this way? Wouldn't this mean make the factor as small as you want to get the best generalization? It seems ridiculous so I am curious what I am missing about the general properties of statistical learning bounds.